# Appending data bytes to binary file with Python

Tags: python, file, python-3.x, append, crc

I want to append a crc that I calculate to an existing binary file.

For example, the crc is 0x55667788.

I want to append 0x55, 0x66, 0x77 and 0x88 to the end of the file.

For example, if I open the file in HexEdit, the last four bytes of the file
will show 0x55667788.

Here is my code so far:

```
fileopen = askopenfilename()
filename = open(fileopen, 'rb+')
filedata = filename.read()
filecrc32 = hex(binascii.crc32(filedata))
filename.seek(0,2)
filename.write(filecrc32)
filename.close()
```

I get the following error:

```
File "C:\Users\cjackel\openfile.py", line 9, in <module>
filename.write(filecrc32)
TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: You're opening the file in *binary* mode, but are trying to write a *text* string. You need to pick an encoding for the string first, or write some other binary data.

Answer (score 4):

The [`hex`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#hex) function returns a *string*. In this case, you've got a string of 10 hex characters representing your 4-byte number, like this:

```
'0x55667788'
```

In Python 2.x, you would be allowed to write this incorrect data to a binary file (it would show up as the 10 bytes `30 78 35 35 36 36 37 37 38 38` rather than the four bytes you want, `55 66 77 88`). Python 3.x is smarter, and only allows you to write `bytes` (or `bytearray` or similar) to a binary file, not `str`.

---

What you want here is not the hex string, but the actual bytes.

The way you described the bytes you want is called [big-endian order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness). On most computers, the "native" order is the opposite, little-endian, which would give you `0x88776655` instead of `0x55667788`.

In Python 3.2+, the simplest way to get that is the [`int.to_bytes`](http://docs.python.org/3.2/library/stdtypes.html#int.to_bytes) method:

```
filecrc = binascii.crc32(filedata).to_bytes(4, byteorder='big', signed=False)
```

(The `signed=False` isn't really necessary, because it's the default, but it's a good way of making it explicit that you're definitely dealing with an unsigned 32-bit integer.)

If you're stuck with earlier versions, you can use the [`struct`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html) module:

```
filecrc = struct.pack('>I', binascii.crc32(filedata))
```

The `>` means big-endian, and the `I` means unsigned 4-byte integer. So, this returns the same thing. In either case, what you get is `b'\x55\x66\x77\x88'` (or, as Python would `repr` it, `b'\Ufw\x88'`).

---

The error is a bit cryptic, because no novice is going to have any idea what "the buffer interface" is (especially since the 3.x documentation calls it the [Buffer Protocol](http://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html), and it's only documented as part of CPython's C extension API…), but effectively it means that you need a [bytes-like object](http://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-bytes-like-object). Usually, this error will mean that you just forgot to encode your string to UTF-8 or some other encoding. But when you were trying to write actual binary data rather than encoded text, it's the same error.

Comment: you could use `binascii.crc32(filedata).to_bytes(4, byteorder='big')` in Python 3.2+

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: Well, I'd probably use an explicit `signed=False` as well, but otherwise, yeah, that's a lot simpler. And I forgot that 3.2 already and it. Thanks!

Comment: I agree. Despite `binascii.crc32()` being documented to return unsigned integers and `signed=False` being default, the explicit `signed=False` makes it easier to read in 6 months then you forgot all about it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to serialize the data. Serialization is the process of getting
the relevant bytes from the whole number. In your case, your CRC is a 
4-byte number. The individual 4 bytes can be retrieved to a list as below:

```
serialized_crc = [(filecrc32 >> 24) & 0xFF,(filecrc32 >> 16) & 0xFF,
                 (filecrc32 >> 8) & 0xFF,filecrc32 & 0xFF]
```

The CRC can be then written to the file by converting to a bytearray as below:

```
filename.write(bytearray(serialized_crc))
```